# ggplot in loop reading CSV files

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I have several `.csv` files with 3 columns. I want to graph the first 2. `ggplot` makes some beautiful graphics but I want to automate the task because there are hundreds of files. I have tried several approaches from this site but none have worked for me. I imagined doing it with `lapply`, but I have failed with every example I came across.

I would appreciate an answer using `ggplot`, but otherwise I'll end up with plot doing the same.

Here is my code:

```
Star2 <-read.table("lista2.txt",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)[,c(1)]

for (i in 1: length(Star2)){ 
   print(ggplot(read.csv(Star2[i]) ,
                aes(x = V1, y = V2, color = "red")) +
           geom_point(colour= "orange") +
           scale_y_reverse(limit = c(6.60,6.45), expand=c(0,0)) +
           ggtitle("CURVA DE FASE") + 
           geom_smooth (colour ="blue" ,span = 0.2) +
           xlab("Fase") + ylab("Mag"))


   ggsave(phase3, file=paste0("plot_", i,".png"), width = 14, height = 10, units = "cm")
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some of what you've attempted. Usually people will help tweak your code, but not write something for you.

Comment: Star2 <-read.table("lista2.txt",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)[,c(1)]

for (i in 1: length(Star2)){
    print(ggplot(read.csv(Star2[i]) ,aes(x = V1, y = V2, color = "red")) + geom_point(colour= "orange") + scale_y_reverse(limit = c(6.60,6.45), expand=c(0,0)) + ggtitle("CURVA DE FASE") + geom_smooth (colour ="blue" ,span = 0.2) + xlab("Fase") + ylab("Mag"))

Comment: What isn't working? you can use ggsave to save the figures.

Comment: Ok, I search for something with ggsave and add it to it. When I did it, it didn't show me any graphs. Paul, are you talking to a super beginner ... thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try put your code in the question using code block would make it a lot easier for others to review and help you.

Comment: Do you have csv files or txt files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(ggplot2)

filenames <- list.files('/folder/of/csv/files', pattern = '\\.csv$', full.names = TRUE)

lapply(filenames, function(x) {
  data <- read.table(x,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  ggplot(data, aes(x = V1, y = V2, color = "red")) +
    geom_point(colour= "orange") +
    scale_y_reverse(limit = c(6.60,6.45), expand=c(0,0)) +
    ggtitle("CURVA DE FASE") + 
    geom_smooth (colour ="blue" ,span = 0.2) +
    xlab("Fase") + ylab("Mag") -> phase3

  ggsave(phase3, file=paste0("plot_", tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(x)),".png"), 
         width = 14, height = 10, units = "cm")
})
```

Comment: Excellent, Ronak! 5 days trying to get this part of the script to come out ..! They were my first attempts with GGplot, I managed to make the graphs one by one but there were many that I needed, my files actually come out as: ". Out" just change .csv for .out in your code: .... infinite thanks! I saw many ideas with the apply family and tried alternatives in my RScript code but none of them worked.